# VBA Access 2010 - prompt user to pick a file and dim the filename as variable

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, vlookup

my Access database exports a report in xls, that needs to be further reworked (some manual adjustments of columns etc. + vlookuping some comments from report from previous day).

Here is the part of the code I created so far:

---

```
Option Compare Database

Function Adjustment()

' First I want to prompt user to select the report from previous day*

Dim f As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolder As String
Dim varItem As Variant

Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
f.AllowMultiSelect = True
If f.Show Then
    For Each varItem In f.SelectedItems
        strFile = Dir(varItem)
        MsgBox (strFile)
    Next
End If
Set f = Nothing

' here my Access database opens current report that has been exported   

  Dim xl As Object
  Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  xl.Workbooks.Open ("I:\Temp\reports.xlsx")
  xl.Visible = True

' in currently open report, I want fill cell I2 and J2 with VLOOKUP function referencing to previously selected file

  Range("I2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC7,'[" & strFile & "]SheetXY'!C7:C12,3,0)"
  Range("J2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC7,'[" & strFile & "]SheetXY!C7:C12,4,0)"

End function
```

**Problem**: I am being prompted every every time to select the file, when formula is being filled in I2 and J2, so how can I disable this and keep Access to reference strFile only once?

**Question**: So far, every first sheet in the refrenced workbook is called SheeyXY, but what if I would like to reference also a different Sheets (let`s say always the first sheet in the workbook no matter what its name is).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking out the .FormularR1C1 from those lines?

Also, I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do with the sheet names, but you could probably hack something together from this?

```
Debug.Print Worksheets(1).Name
```

or

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    Debug.Print ws.Name
Next
```

UPDATE:

Try this, and report back?

```
With xl.Worksheets(1)
    .Range("I2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC7,[" & strFile & "]Sheet1!C7:C12,3,0)"
    .Range("J2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC7,[" & strFile & "]Sheet1!C7:C12,4,0)"
End With
```

So with the extra clarification of which range, and without the extra apostrophe

Comment: Hello and thanks for advice. I removed formula and have just: Range("I2") = "=VLOOKUP(RC7,'[" & strFile & "]SheetXY'!C7:C12,3,0)" which works well. But still I am being prompted to select the file once again (although I did that at the beginning), once the code arrives to this line (but for the second vlookup it will not ask me any more). What am I doing wrong? :-(

Comment: I've had one idea which seems to work for me, I will put it in my answer so it has the right format

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this ..

```
Option Compare Database

Function Adjustment(SheetName as String) '---> add parameter such as "SheetXY"

' First I want to prompt user to select the report from previous day*

Dim f As Object    
Dim strFolder As String
Dim varItem As Variant
Static strFile As String

If strFile = "" Then
  Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
  f.AllowMultiSelect = True
  If f.Show Then
      For Each varItem In f.SelectedItems
          strFile = Dir(varItem)
          MsgBox (strFile)
      Next
  End If
  Set f = Nothing
Endif 

' here my Access database opens current report that has been exported   

  Dim xl As Object
  Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  xl.Workbooks.Open ("I:\Temp\reports.xlsx")
  xl.Visible = True

' in currently open report, I want fill cell I2 and J2 with VLOOKUP function referencing to previously selected file

  Range("I2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC7,'[" & strFile & "]" & SheetName & "'!C7:C12,3,0)"
  Range("J2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC7,'[" & strFile & "]" & SheetName & "'!C7:C12,4,0)"

End function
```